# Can't resolve 'fs' in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, pdf.js

I would like to use `pdf.js` in an Electron app. This lib uses several node module such as `fs` or `zlib`. When launching the app, I have many errors, one for each failing native node module import:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/antoine/Desktop/black-charts-desktop/node_modules/pdf.js-extract/lib/pdfjs'

Yet, I have authorized node in my main window:

```js
webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
```

How to use native node module in my Electron app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the version of Electron used and the type of solution to use webpack.
The use of webpack is possible with this solution:

https://webpack.electron.build/

BTW: in general, it is not recommended to use nodeIntegration, however, I personally disagree. VSCode, Teams, Postman based on Electron successfully use nodeIntegration....

In the `"electron" version: "^20.0.3"`, to build applications without IPC, in the renderer process, you need to add the `@electron/remote` package.

In addition, in package.json:

```
  "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      "./node_modules/@electron/remote/**"
    ]
  },
```

If we want to use Typescript and Sass:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^20.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^23.5.1",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.8.2",
    "electron-webpack-ts": "^4.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "4.42.1"
  },
```

and the scripts can look like this, for example:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev --host 0.0.0.0",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "dist": "npm run compile && electron-builder".
}
```